# VSTS Docker task yaml file to pull image from docker hub

Tags: azure-pipelines-build-task

We are trying to create a build pipeline in vsts using yaml files.
There’s one step which requires us to pull an image from docker hub. I’m unclear on how to create the step in yaml. 
From the docker task in documentation, it doesn’t seem to have examples for pull command in docker. I have tried following:

```
- task: Docker@1
  displayName: 'pull an image'
  inputs:
    command: 'pull'
    imageName: ‘docker.io/nvidia/cuda@sha256:33add9c50ab76b8f3a92187c0418ed600d5bea27690fda40711122fdc28ce2f4’
```

and
    - task: Docker@1
      displayName: 'pull an image'
      inputs:
        command: 'pull docker.io/nvidia/cuda@sha256:33add9c50ab76b8f3a92187c0418ed600d5bea27690fda40711122fdc28ce2f4'
The first one becomes this when actually running:
Docker pull 
Second one makes the build complain that 'pull docker.io/nvidia/cuda@sha256:33add9c50ab76b8f3a92187c0418ed600d5bea27690fda40711122fdc28ce2f4' is not a docker command.
Could you advice on what’s the correct way to execute this action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'nvidia/cuda’ is public repositor. For pulling an image from ‘nvidia/cuda’ or public repository, following yaml file with image name worked for me.

```
steps:
```

`- task: Docker@1
  displayName: pull 
  inputs:
        command: pull
        arguments: 'nvidia/cuda:9.2-runtime-ubuntu18.04' # Pull an image ‘nvidia/cuda’ with tag ‘9.2-runtime-ubuntu18.04’. You can find ‘nvidia/cuda’ tags here https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda/tags/`